# HTML title attribute instead of the tag content

Tags: html, user-interface, accessibility, user-experience, emoji

Considering accessibility, is it good to use:

```
<a href="about.html" title="About"></a>
```

without any content, instead of:

```
<a href="about.html">About</a>
```

Update: Here's a live demo, supposing that an appropriate font is available. I actually use [RichStyle font](http://richstyle.org/font.php).

```css
a[href="about.html"]:before {
    /* 1F6C8  CIRCLED INFORMATION SOURCE = information */
    content: "\1F6C8";
}
```

```html
<a href="about.html" title="About"></a>
```

Comment: @Ansas R - If I'm not mistaken, the title attribute is to show a tooltip when you hover over the element. In your first case, you will not see any text (element seems missing or invisible), but on the second you will see the link's text.

Comment: This might be better asked on [ux.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @FrederikMoller I'll use CSS for sure.

Comment: @Tim Is it possible to *move* it there?

Comment: As far as I know, only mods can migrate questions to other sites, so you would either have to get the attention of a moderator, or just post this again on ux.SE yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Good" is a not very well defined term.

Is it accessible to screen readers - yes. According to the WAI-ARIA name calculation algorithm, title will be used to calculate the name. It is step H and is referred to as the tooltip.

http://www.w3.org/TR/accname-aam-1.1/#mapping_additional_nd_te

However, that is not the whole picture, because there also needs to be a visible name for the link that is accessible by sighted keyboard-only users. Title attributes are only displayed in HTML when you mouse over an item.

Therefore, this technique will only be accessible if there is some other visible indication of what the link is and this visible indicator adheres to all the other accessibility requirements.

Comment: Should this visual indicator be in the HTML code itself, or CSS solutions are enough?

Comment: @AnasR. the technique you use to solve this is irrelevant. What matters is whether it works as required/intended. That being said if you create a jsfiddle with a specific solution, I can tell you if I think it will work.

Comment: @AnasR. You should at less modify your HTML content, as your code presuppose that you are using some CSS to include image which convey important information (http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F3.html).

Answer (score 4):

Here is some good information regarding use of the title attribute with the anchor tag.

[w3.org - supplementing link text with the title attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H33.html)

> The objective of this technique is to demonstrate how to use a title attribute on an anchor element to provide additional text describing a link. The title attribute is used to provide additional information to help clarify or further describe the purpose of a link. If the supplementary information provided through the title attribute is something the user should know before following the link, such as a warning, then it should be provided in the link text rather than in the title attribute.
>
> Because of the extensive user agent limitations in supporting access to the title attribute, authors should use caution in applying this technique. For this reason, it is preferred that the author use technique C7: Using CSS to hide a portion of the link text (CSS) or H30: Providing link text that describes the purpose of a link for anchor elements.

Answer (score 1):

The WCAG says in his normative section (2.4.4) : **"The purpose of each link can be determined from the link text alone"** (http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#navigation-mechanisms).

WCAG also says that you can "supplement" the link text with the title attribute, **so it excludes the `title` attribute from the definition of "link text"**.

Conclusion: you must provide a link text like in your second example:

```
 <a href="about.html">About</a>
```

Although this is not explicitly defined in this normative section of the WCAG, the "link text" is defined in the techniques as being the content of the inner text of a link including images alternative.

See the two following and complementary techniques for more informations:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20150226/H30.html
http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H33.html

---

EDIT: one comment illustrated that my answer lacked of some examples

Please note that WCAG2.0 and WAI-ARIA are two complementary and distinct guidelines and that you can provide additional informations which can be exposed to accessibility API if it's necessary. But in no case, you should consider that exposing an information to the accessibility API is sufficient enough for those not using Assistive technologies.

So the following example is wrong as aria-label can't be accessed within an user agent without the use of assistive technologies

```
<a href="about.html" aria-label="About"></a>
```

The following is also wrong:

```
<a href="about.html" title="About">
   <img width="100" height="100" src="about.png" alt="" /></a>
```

Although your link exposes an "accessible name" to the Accessibility API (WAI-ARIA), it does not provide a "link text" as specified by the WCAG normative guideline (and apparently means that [a significant image is used as decorative](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F3.html)).

**So if your link only contains an image, this image should be present in the HTML code, and be correctly entitled with the alt attribute**

EDIT 2: You can read the following blog post to illustrate the problem with the sole use of the title attribute https://silktide.com/i-thought-title-text-improved-accessibility-i-was-wrong/

Comment: the link text is calculated using the algorithm I referenced in my answer. That however is not enough, as I pointed-out. Because you can create a link text that is not visible and you need a visible communication of that text if the text itself is not visible.

Comment: All that matters is the "accessible name", content is only one way to calculate that and in fact those techniques show a combination of ways - including the use of the alt attribute on an image inside the anchor. Also - remember that techniques are not normative and they can become obsolete.

Comment: That is referring to the "accessible name" - the WAI-ARIA algorithms are newer than the WCAG 2 spec. The techniques are informative, not normative and as I mentioned, can become obsolete or superseded

Comment: Thanks for your request for clarifications, I edited my answer to give a few examples and edited the link to point to the normative section as you pointed.

Comment: Now your answer is actually worse

Comment: The title attribute is semantically a "hint" as far as accessibility is concerned. In the absence of any other text, it serves the purpose of the accessible name as step H in the algorithm referenced in my answer. All you need to make a link accessible is an accessible name and a visual equivalent (which can be an image). It is that simple and a title attribute can be used for that purpose and it does actually work in practice (which is the most important part as far as WCAG is concerned).

Answer (score 0):

Its not bad or good. Because if you want to do button with image and no text with the a tag you will do something like.

```
<a href="about.html" title="About"></a>
```

Just make sure you put a style for your a so users will be able to click on it.

Comment: And this will be a bad choice for a lot of reasons (Accessibility, SEO, text browsers, separation of presentation and content...)

Answer (score 0):

For SEO purposes it is good. You can aim at keywords with title attribute. so, It is good to use. it gives user an idea about what he is going to do by clicking after it. I use it often.

Comment: I have found that SEO and Accessibility often times go hand-in-hand.